# Where I save the data that I use latter with php?

Tags: php, save, client

Let's say an user click on a button. The client receive some data that I use latter. If user receive number 2, next time when click again I need to know was 2. The user don't see this number.

I use hidden input for latter use
or 
cookies/sessions 
or 
other things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions will work:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['number'] = 2;
```

- Cookie values are available to the user because they're stored on the client's computer.
- Hidden fields can be viewed via the source.
- Session values are stored on the server (or in a database). The only thing should be available to the client is the session ID, which is usually stored in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing data against particular user into database, Try MySQL its very easy and fast accessible db.